# Need to convert to integer and then sum of the Plucked data ruby 2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need SUM of the plucked timings.

I did

```
@dailystatus_infos.task_times.pluck(:total_min)
```

I got following

```
["00:00:00", "1:52:00", "00:00:00", "00:02:28", "1:54:00"]
```

output. `[Hour:Minute:Second]` format

Now I need to convert those Minutes to integer and sum of it.

Comment: Having formatted strings inside a database is of little use. It would be better to store the numeric values instead, i.e. the number of seconds. If you had that, you could simply call `@dailystatus_infos.task_times.sum(:total_min)` and let the database calculate the result.

Answer (score 2):

> I need SUM of the plucked timings

I'd start by writing a helper method to convert the `hh:mm:ss` string to seconds. A regular expression would work:

```
def to_seconds(string)
  string.match(/(?<hours>\d+):(?<minutes>\d+):(?<seconds>\d+)/) do |m|
    m[:hours].to_i * 3600 + m[:minutes].to_i * 60 + m[:seconds].to_i
  end
end

to_seconds('00:00:12') #=> 12
to_seconds('00:01:00') #=> 60
to_seconds('00:01:12') #=> 72
```

Now you can [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) the seconds via:

```
total_mins = ["00:00:00", "1:52:00", "00:00:00", "00:02:28", "1:54:00"]

total_mins.sum { |str| to_seconds(str) }
#=> 13708
```

And, if necessary, convert that back to `h:mm:ss` via [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod):

```
seconds = 13708

hours, seconds = seconds.divmod(3600)
minutes, seconds = seconds.divmod(60)

format('%d:%02d:%02d', hours, minutes, seconds)
#=> "3:48:28"
```

Answer (score 2):

We first determine the total seconds:

```
arr = ["00:00:00", "1:52:00", "00:00:00", "00:02:28", "1:54:00"]
```

```
s = arr.sum do |str|
  str.split(':').reduce(0) { |t, s| t * 60 + s.to_i }
end
  #=> 13708
```

and then manipulate `s` as desired. The number of minutes, for example, equals

```
s.fdiv(60)
  #=> 228.46666666666667
```

which might be rounded or truncated.

Comment: `str.split(':').reduce(0) { |t, s| t * 60 + s.to_i }` – no need for an index :-)

Comment: @Stefan, thanks. Something like that was rumbling it my grey cells but didn't make its way to my cerebrum.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```rb
total_minutes = @dailystatus_infos.task_times.pluck(:total_min)
total_minutes.map { |t| (::Time.parse(t).seconds_since_midnight / 60).to_i }.sum

arr = ["00:00:00", "1:52:00", "00:00:00", "00:02:28", "1:54:00"]

arr.map { |t| ::Time.parse(t).seconds_since_midnight / 60 }.sum.to_i
=> 228
```

Comment: Note that `Time` doesn't work if the durations (or their sum) exceed 24 hours.

Answer (score -1):

You get the minute by splitting on `:`. Then `map` and `sum`.

```rb
ary = ["00:00:00", "1:52:00", "00:00:00", "00:02:28", "1:54:00"]
ary.map{ |s| s.split(':')[1].to_i }.sum #=> 108 (0 + 52 + 0 + 2 + 54)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(0 + 112 + 0 + 2 + 54)`?

Comment: With "convert those Minutes to integer" I understood convert **only** the minutes to integer.